# Program that puts the taskbar on all monitors

Tags: windows-8, multi-monitor

Windows 8 only puts the taskbar on the primary monitor. Is there a software that will put the taskbar on all monitors? I have three, so it needs to work on any amount, not just dual-monitors. I'd like it to include the clock as well. I want it to look like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: I think what you are asking for is to put the "notification area" (or "system tray") on all displays.   What you called the "start bar" in a comment on diedie2's answer is, in fact, the task bar.  Unfortunately, I dint know of any way to make the notification area show on all displays.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is built in Windows 8.

[image]

For Windows 7 or below, or if you want extra functionality, you could try [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) or [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/)

Comment: It's only on my primary monitor on windows 8, not all monitors.

Comment: I have that checked but it doesn't work for some reason. This is what my monitors look like: https://i.imgur.com/L2kroOk.jpg - Unchecking that option (Show taskbar on all displays) makes the entire start bar go away.

Comment: I don't have a Multi-monitor setup, so I was not sure what to expect in detail. I did have it in the past, and then I used UltraMon as I suggested. It's not free, but I don't know a free alternative. There is a free trail, so try before you buy ;-)

Comment: It works for me using that option. Could it be graphics card specific?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com) for this, but haven't tested on Windows 8.1, although should probably work. The taskbar(s) should all be with notification with this

https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Taskbar

[image]